# What happens when you deallocate a pointer twice or more in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, allocation, delete-operator

```
int main() {
    Employee *e = new Employee();

    delete e;
    delete e;
    ...
    delete e;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *out of cucumber error* restart universe.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Its a simple & straightforward question.  Just because you think it's an elementary question doesn't mean it should be d/v'ed.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You get *undefined behaviour* if you try to `delete` an object through a pointer more than once.

This means that pretty much anything can happen from 'appearing to work' to 'crashing' or something completely random.

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't crash. But what I think is that you might deallocate memory that other part of your program is using.

Comment: It might not crash at that moment. But if it corrupts part of the heap, then there's a significant chance that a crash could happen at some arbitrary point afterwards. However, it could become something of a lurking time-bomb. Not causing any problem until later when some seemingly unrelated action happens to touch the corrupted part and then *boom*

Answer (score 20):

It's undefined behavior, so anything can happen.

What's likely to happen is bad.  Typically, the free store is a carefully managed system of free and allocated blocks, and `new` and `delete` do bookkeeping to keep everything in a consistent state.  If you `delete` again, the system is likely to do the same bookkeeping on invalid data, and suddenly the free store is in an inconsistent state.  This is known as "heap corruption".

Once that happens, anything you do with `new` or `delete` may have unpredictable results, which can include attempting to write outside the application's memory area, silently corrupting data, erroneously thinking there's no more memory, or double or overlapping allocation.  If you're lucky, the program will crash soon, although you'll still have problems figuring out why.  If you're unlucky, it will continue to run with bad results.

Answer (score 13):

Aside from the old saw about "undefined behavior" meaning anything could happen from nothing to a gateway to the seventh circle of the inferno opening up in main memory, *in practice* what will usually happen in most implementations is that the program will continue to run past the deletes, and then mysteriously crash sometime later in some unrelated memory allocation.

Comment: Yes, and that's one of the better things that can happen.

Comment: often When I get the mysterious memory crashes, I *WISH* a gateway to the seventh circle of the inferno had opened up in main memory instead...

Answer (score 4):

You are likely venturing into 'undefined behavior' territory.

On many systems this will cause a crash; for example, on my Linux machine:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./cctest: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000d59900 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0x7f399f4cbdd6]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6c)[0x7f399f4d074c]
./cctest[0x400a7a]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7f399f474abd]
./cctest[0x400959]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're really lucky it will crash. What normally happens is it stores up karma until your CEO is demonstrating the code to your most important new customer when it will corrupt/destroy all of their data.

In checked or debug builds often this kind of thing is caught, but it can go completely undetected and cause havoc later. This is especially profound when multiple threads get involved.

Answer (score 3):

If you are worried this might happen in your apps, either stop using raw pointers completely, so that you don't need delete (eg switch over to `shared_ptr`) or always set pointers to `NULL` (or 0, or better still `nullptr`) after you delete them. Calling delete on a null pointer is guaranteed to do nothing.

Comment: I've always disliked the latter solution. Deleting a pointer twice is bad, and setting pointers to null is just going to hide the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's not safe, and it's undefined what might actually happen:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.2

Answer (score 0):

Even though sometimes we can access the memory location after deleting ptr.
we shouldn't delete same pointer again or assign value to that pointer( leads to inconsistent behavior).

But we can use same pointer variable to point different memory address ( valid memory)

```
int *p = new int(10);
std::cout << "in main" << std::endl;
std::cout <<*p << std::endl;
std::cout << p << std::endl;
std::cout << &p<< std::endl;
delete p;
std::cout << "in main2 after delete" << std::endl;
std::cout <<*p << std::endl;
std::cout << p << std::endl;
std::cout << &p<< std::endl;

p = new int(100);
std::cout << "in main3" << std::endl;
std::cout <<*p << std::endl;
std::cout << p << std::endl;
std::cout << &p<< std::endl;
```

leads to output

```
in main
10
0x558b597a8eb0
0x7fff8f7a5ba0
in main2 after delete
0
0x558b597a8eb0
0x7fff8f7a5ba0
in main3
100
0x558b597a8eb0
0x7fff8f7a5ba0
```