# Using delete crashes my computer

Tags: c++, crash, delete-operator

When I put delete in the destructor of my class, the system crashes when I exit the program.

For example I use wxWidgets radiobutton:

```
wxRadioButton *rb1;
```

I initialize it this way in the constructor of my class:

```
rb1 = new wxRadioButton(this, ID_RADIOBUTTON_1, _T("&Bied"), wxPoint(310,40), wxSize(110,20),wxRB_GROUP);
```

and I delete in the destructor of that class:

```
  if (rb1) delete rb1;
```

but it crashes every time, I have to put it on comment so it won't crash, (but I know its not the right way to deal with it).

Comment: The `if` is not helping at all.

Comment: Could it be that you are copying instances of your class and you haven't written a copy constructor and assignment operator?

Comment: Let me guess ... you haven't defined a copy constructor and/or assignment operator for your class. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: If you simply want it created by the constructor and destroyed by the destructor, why mess around with `new` at all? Just make it a member.

Comment: (If you do need dynamic allocation for some reason, use smart pointers. If you don't want to do that for some reason, remember the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722)).

Comment: Reading this, you aren't suppose to call delete in wxWidgets: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Avoiding_Memory_Leaks#The_wxWidgets-specific_part UI frameworks tend to do this, make sure you follow their guidelines carefully.

Comment: @GManNickG : in the wiki, is it said that you need to delete objects on the heap and that's what i have here i think

Comment: @IonOne: From the page: "This is done with the `Destroy()`-method of wxWindow. Instead of using `delete`, you must use `myWindow->Destroy()`, which will wait until next idle loop and then do something like delete `myWindow;`."

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not deleting the pointer twice? Doing so could result in [nasty crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746677/what-happens-when-you-deallocate-a-pointer-twice-or-more-in-c).

Alternatively, simply switch to using a member variable instead, so you won't have to deal with the allocation and deallocation.