# C++: Heap error when dynamically allocating array through nested class?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays, dynamic-allocation

I'm trying to allocate memory for `Uint8` type array through a nested class. When I'm doing so I think it runs to heap error and prompts the window that says **Debug Assertion Error. Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)**. My code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dcmtk/dcmdata/dctk.h"
using namespace std;

class test
{
public:
    int a;
    Uint8 * b;
    test()
    {}
    test(int c)
    {
        a=c;
        b = new Uint8[a];
    }
    ~test()
    {
        delete [] b;
    }
};

class subTest
{
public:
    test h;
    subTest()
    {}
    subTest(test g)
    {
        h=g;
    }
    ~subTest()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    subTest f(test(5));
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        f.h.b[i] = Uint8((i*2)+1);
        cout<< int(f.h.b[i])<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Could you find what mistake I'm doing?

Thanks.

Comment: Start by following the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). Even better, use an `std::vector<Uint8>`.

Comment: My mistake I forgot to mention the error. The question is updated now.

Comment: Maybe that rule must be upgraded to rule of four, with move constructor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments and by others, the problem occurs because you did not follow the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C++_programming)), that is, since you had to define a custom destructor(to delete the dynamically allocated memory), you should at least define a custom copy constructor(which does a deep copy of the array, that is, it allocates new memory and copies the content of the old array) and a custom copy assignment operator(that does essentially the same, so you could implement one in terms of the other).

Example code for a copy constructor(suboptimal, of course):

```
test(const test &other)
{
  a=other.a
  b=new Uint8[a];
  for(size_t i=0;i<a;++i)
    b[i]=other.b[i];
}
```

As can be seen, this would involve a little work and is quite tedious, which is why you should prefarably follow the [rule of zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/) and use classes that already deal with ownership issues intrinsically(which in your case should propably be a std::vector), so instead of dealing with your dynamically allocated array directly, change it to something akin to this:

```
class test
{
  public:
  std::vector<Uint8> b;

  test(int size)
  {
    b.resize(size);
  }
}
```

And all your problems vanish, because std::vector deals with the required deep copy itself, without your class having to worry about it.

I hope this helps ;-)

Answer (score 2):

when you are copying an object in constructor:

```
subTest(test g)
{
    h=g;
}
```

and an object contains a pointer like in your `test class` case, you need to do a deep copy in your own specified [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor): allocate new storage and copy array content into it. Otherwise you ends up with two (or maybe more later) objects with pointer into same memory. This is why

```
~test()
{
    delete [] b;
}
```

will cause an error (it is undefined behavior in addition). As a side note: you should also take a look on a "Rule of three".

[Rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)

[What happens when you deallocate a pointer twice or more in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2746677/1141471)

Answer (score 0):

In `subTest f(test(5));` you create an temp `test` object, copy it in `f`. `f` contains a copy of temp `test` object with a copy of `b` pointer. Temp object destructs, pointers are invalid. Both in temp (destroyed) object and it's copy in `f`. `f.h.b[i] = ...` BOOM! Heap corruption. What do you need is shared_ptr. From [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or from [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).

Comment: So, what's the solution to avoid the boom?

Comment: Aha! I just removed `delete [] b;` and deleting it manually outside, that improves it. Is that enough to avoid the explosion?

Comment: Yes, you will avoid the explosion. I recommend you to implement copy constructor for test and resolve b ownership somehow. You can create a new one and copy it in there, for example.