# deallocation of same pointer twice not giving error if I make the pointer NULL

Tags: c++

I tried to deallocate same pointer twice and it failed, but if I follow the same steps with not making it NULL the code runs fine.

```
 #include <iostream>

    struct MyClass {
      MyClass() {std::cout << "Allocated and Constructed" << std::endl ;} 
    };

    int main () {
      // allocates and constructs five objects:
      MyClass * p1 = new MyClass[5];

      delete[] p1;
      delete[] p1; // The code will succeed if I comment this line of code
      p1=NULL;
      delete[] p1;
      delete[] p1;

      return 0;
    }
```

I see a good answer to the question [What happens when you deallocate a pointer twice or more in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746677/what-happens-when-you-deallocate-a-pointer-twice-or-more-in-c) but what makes it run if I make it NULL, shouldn't be the same behaviour to follow for both the cases?

Comment: Deleting NULL is well-defined and does nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to delete a NULL pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190703/is-it-safe-to-delete-a-null-pointer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to deallocate only what you allocate. You allocate five instances of `MyClass` with `new[]`. So that's what you need to deallocate.

You're not deallocating any pointers. Pointers don't need to be deallocated unless you dynamically allocated them, and your code doesn't dynamically allocate any pointers.

When you make the pointer `nullptr` (or `NULL`), it doesn't point to anything. So calling `delete` on it has no effect. The C++ standard chose to make calling `delete` (or `delete[]`) on a null pointer do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

`delete[] p1;` doesn't *ususally* change the actual value of `p1`. (Although the C++ standard states that it *can* set `p1` to `nullptr` on doing this, no compiler I've worked with actually does this).

So the behaviour on a second call to `delete[] p1;` is undefined since your program no longer owns that memory.

Some programmers consider it good practice to set `p1 = nullptr` explicitly after a `delete[]` since then a subsequent `delete` is benign. But doing that can hide other memory management issues your program has (why *would* your program attempt to `delete` the same block of memory more than once?), so I'd advise against it.

Comment: Although most programmers consider that to be bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

From the standard, 5.3.5$2 Delete [expr.delete] (bold by me)

> In the first alternative (delete object), the value of the operand of
>   delete may be a **null pointer value**, a pointer to a non-array object
>   created by a previous new-expression, or a pointer to a subobject
>   (1.8) representing a base class of such an object (Clause 10). If not,
>   the behavior is undefined. In the second alternative (delete array),
>   the value of the operand of delete may be a **null pointer value** or a
>   pointer value that resulted from a previous array
>   new-expression.<sup>81</sup> If not, the behavior is undefined.

It explains why delete a pointer twice is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and delete a null pointer is well defined.