# Deleting multiple char pointers

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble deleting these two pointers:

```
int *p = new int;
    char * string1 = new char[20];
    char * string2 = new char[25];
    strcpy(string1, "Sheldon");

    string2 = string1;
    delete p;
    delete[] string2; //this works without the next line
    delete[] string1; //when I add this, it fails at string2 = string1
```

I'm using the memory leak detection with

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

When I run he program without "delete[] string1," it gives me "{66} normal block at 0x0075E300, 25 bytes long." So "delete[] string2" is deleting string1. Which doesn't make sense to me, but I'm guessing it has to do with the assignment. I tried looking up stuff about it, but nothing has worked.

Comment: `string2 = string1` - are you under the impression that that's a string copy? And why are you using `char *`s instead of `std::string`s in C++ anyway?

Comment: No one has time for this. Use `std::string`.

Comment: You are trying to delete the same pointer twice. The other one is lost after `string2 = string1;`.

Comment: Not just an assignment leading to double-delete; it's also a *memory leak*.

Comment: @user2357112 please don't forget to accept the answer you found most useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code fails because you're deleting the same pointer twice, which results in **undefined behavior** (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746677/what-happens-when-you-deallocate-a-pointer-twice-or-more-in-c)). After the statement `string2 = string1;` the pointers `string1` and `string2` hold the same address, and you can no longer access the address stored in`string2` before the assginment, which also results in a **memory leak**.

If you wanted to copy `string1` to `string2`, you shold use `strncpy(string2, string1, 20)` (see [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/)) in which case the pointers themselves remain unchanged and the deallocation code you provided is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to delete the memory assigned to `string2` before being assigned `string1`.

AFter asssignment, `string2` and `string1` are one and same. Check below code for reference:

```
int *p = new int;
char * string1 = new char[20];
char * string2 = new char[25];
strcpy(string1, "Sheldon");
delete[] string2; //this would prevent memory leak
string2 = string1;
delete p;

delete[] string1; //now you are releasing the memory held by string2 too.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already identified, the problem in your code is the assignment. 
After `string2 = string1;`, both `string2` and `string1` point to the same memory location. Therefore, when you call  `delete[] string2` you are free the memory pointed by `string1`. Then you call `delete[] string1` and you get *undefined behaviour* as the memory to which the pointer points has already been freed. That is, you are free twice the same pointer.

Also, your code contains a memory leak because you are not de-allocating the initial memory reserved for `string2`. What you should do is :

```
    delete[] string2;  // release the memory for string2
    string2 = string1; // string1, string2 point to the same memory area
    delete[] string1; // release the memory for string1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char * string1 = new char[20];
char * string2 = new char[25];
strcpy(string1, "Sheldon");

string2 = string1;
delete p;
delete[] string2; //this works without the next line
delete[] string1; //when I add this, it fails at string2 = string1
```

Three problem:

1. The original char array which the original variable string2
   pointed to would never be deleted. (memory leak)
2. By `delete[] string2;` the original char array which string1
   pointed to would be deleted. (recycle unintended memory)
3. By `delete[] string1;` after `delete[] string2;`, the memory that
   already deleted, would be deleted again.(fail)